# Local fonts not loaded correctly?

Tags: laravel, puppeteer, laravel-blade, browsershot

I am using [Browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot), which is based on [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to create PDF from HTML. The HTML-source is rendered Laravel-Blade.

This is my blade-template that is being rendered:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset(mix('/css/app.css')) }}" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<div class="relative h-screen">
    @include('pdf.partials.header')
    <div class="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0">
        @include('pdf.partials.footer')
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.css` contains `@font-faces` like:

```
 /* lato-100 - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Lato';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 100;
        src: local('Lato Hairline'), local('Lato-Hairline'),
        url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100.svg#Lato') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        font-display: swap;
    }
    /* lato-100italic - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Lato';
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 100;
        src: local('Lato Hairline Italic'), local('Lato-HairlineItalic'),
        url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-100italic.svg#Lato') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        font-display: swap;
    }
```

Now if I try to create a pdf, those fonts are not loaded correctly.

If I trace that down using:

```
$view      = view('pdf', compact('data'));
$body_html = $view->render();

$requests = \Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot::html($body_html)->format('A4')
    ->margins(8, 22, 8, 22)->showBackground()->addChromiumArguments([
        'font-render-hinting' => 'none',
    ])->waitUntilNetworkIdle()->ignoreHttpsErrors()
    ->triggeredRequests();

dump($requests);
```

I see those requests:

```
4 => array:1 [
"url" => "http://example.test/fonts/lato-v16-latin-300.woff2?98d8cf792834c0bef59c2be99dc3533d"
]
```

I am able to open this path using my browser and the virtual machine Laravel lives in, is able to do so, too:

```
root@example:~# http://example.test/fonts/ibm-plex-mono-v5-latin-200.woff2?4b65d6136cfc2097c4a2103960f00a2c
Resolving example.test (example.test)... 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1
Connecting to example.test (example.test)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

But the fonts are still not applied.

Now if I simply use Google fonts like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset(mix('/css/app.css')) }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></head>

<body>
<div class="relative h-screen">
    @include('pdf.partials.header')
    <div class="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0">
        @include('pdf.partials.footer')
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

it works just fine.

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We had success using [this tool](https://amio.github.io/embedded-google-fonts/) to get the base64 version of the google font we were trying to use locally. Embedding the font as base64 right in the CSS allowed us to get around this issue.